# Google Chrome doesn't open any pages

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

kUbuntu 22.04, Chrome 103

Chrome doesn't open any pages, even `chrome://settings/`, all pages becomes unresponsive after 10+ seconds.

```
$ google-chrome-stable --enable-logging=stderr --log-level=0

[5317:5354:0706/124944.403153:WARNING:external_pref_loader.cc(300)] You are using an old-style extension deployment method (external_extensions.json), which will soon be deprecated. (see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)
[5317:5317:0706/124944.429464:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[5317:5317:0706/124944.498042:WARNING:extension_sync_service.cc(505)] Could not add pending extension for pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia
[5317:5317:0706/124946.766529:INFO:render_frame_host_impl.cc(11505)] RenderFrameHostImpl::MaybeGenerateCrashReport url = , status = 4, exit
```

But, if i run it with `--v=1` flag, everything is ok.

Comment: do you get any output in terminal when you run it from there?

Comment: @Esther added it to question

Comment: Adding the `--v=1` flag is a logging standard, please run with `--enable-logging --v=1`, and gather and post the logs generated from that. To find these logs, see [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en#zippy=%2Clinux)

Comment: @David `--enable-logging --v=1` firstly spams a lot, secondly problem doesn't appear as I wrote before